# Saving Button's text in my listview which is connected to SQLite Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, button

I have a listview that have buttons in every row and is connected to my SQLite database.

Here's the code:

```
public class UpdateActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, View.OnClickListener  {

ListView listView;
SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_update);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    Appliances db = new Appliances(getApplicationContext());


    Cursor cursor = db.getAllApp();
    // The desired columns to be bound
    String[] columns = new String[] { Appliances.KEY_APPNAME,Appliances.KEY_ONOFF };

    // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text, R.id.right};

    // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data
    // as well as the layout information
    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row_view,
            cursor, columns, to, 0) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row =  super.getView(position, convertView, parent);



            View right = row.findViewById(R.id.right);
            right.setTag(position);
            right.setOnClickListener(UpdateActivity.this);

            return row;
        }
    };



    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    EditText myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myFilter);
    myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
        }
    });

    dataAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
            Appliances db = new Appliances(getApplicationContext());
                return db.getAppliancesByName(constraint.toString());

        }
    });
}

   public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.right:
            Button tog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.right);
            Appliances db = new Appliances(getApplicationContext());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Right Accessory "+v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Integer i = (Integer) v.getTag();
            if(tog.getText().toString().equals("ON")){
                //db.update_on(i, "ON");
                tog.setText("OFF");
            }else if(tog.getText().toString().equals("OFF")){
           // db.update_on(i, "OFF");   
            tog.setText("ON");
            }

            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Whenever I click the Button in the second row in my listview, the button in the first row changes its text. In short, The if-condition is only applicable in the first row.

Every button must change its text into "ON" or "OFF" everytime I click them AND saves their texts in the SQLite database in their corresponding row.

Screenshot: 
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I may be entirely wrong ..but I strongly guess that it is because of Id.

Repalce this Code :

```
Button tog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.right);
```

With

```
Button tog = (Button)v
```

Becuase you have already assigned the id to that view and passed that to the onClick Method and When you reassign then it refers to the Button from your main layout.